# WPF How to visit each child of a UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

The UserControl is composed of two labels and one Textbox.Some relative codes are below

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Company {get; set; }
    public TextBox TrueText;
    private void Input_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.TrueText = sender as TextBox;
    }
}
```

xaml

```
<Viewbox >
    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Content="{Binding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="180"/>
        <TextBox Margin="180,0,0,0" Name="Input"  Loaded="Input_Loaded" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="待输入" Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" MinHeight="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Height="18"/>
        <Label Content="{Binding Company}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="18" Margin="300,1,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

Then I want to get the Input in TextBox of each UserControl.But I can't get the children of the UniformGrid.

I have tried to use GetChildObject, but in this way I can't access his related properties
This is my wrong code`your text`

```
IEnumerable<UserControl1> list = (IEnumerable<UserControl1>)Grid1.GetChildObjects();
int i = 1;
double[] num = { 0 };
foreach (var u in list)
{
    i++;
    num[i] = Convert.ToDouble(u.TrueText.Text);
}
```

Any solution will be truly appreciated

Comment: What is GetChildObjects? There is a `Children` property of type UIElementCollection. You can cast its elements to the desired type, like `var textBox = (TextBox)Grid1.Children[1];`. Or you use LINQ like `var textBox = Grid1.Children.OfType<TextBox>().First();`

Comment: This sort of requirement is usually handled by using an itemscontrol. Bind a list or obsevablecollection<t> of viewmodels and template them out into ui.  You can then work with the bound collection. It's a bad idea to use the ui as a data store.  I could do with a pinned statement or something I link.  Must have written pretty much this statement about 6 times in the last few days.